# Stackless Python and PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, stackless, python-stackless

What experiences do you have with Stackless Python and PyQt?

Issues i would be happy if people address:

1. Compilation of PyQt for Stackless: does PyQt need to be compiled especially for Stackless? is the compilation smooth? problems with bindings etc.
2. Stability: any unexpected crashes, freezes, pauses and other weirdities?
3. Memory Management: any hints of memory leaks. comparison of RAM needed for a Stackless/Plain Vanilla PyQt applications
4. Software Engineering Empowerment: very short outline of flow-of-control models for Stackless-powered PyQt applications
5. Lessons learned: any painful lesson learned, traps to be avoided, problems to tackle you might have experienced

Be Happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to go down this path several months ago and decided it was not worth the effort.

I was able to run a binary install of PyQt (on Windows) against a stackless version of Python, but I found that I had to manually go in and change some of the files.  I was getting an error message (sorry, I forget what it was), and google search led to a solution from several years ago.  Newer code did not include the old fix, so the change was not too difficult and (if I remember correctly) it was in python, so no recompile was necessary.

But that was a deal breaker for me. Qt updates come out regularly, as do updates to PyQt, and I didn't want to be continually fixing the code.  Stackless and PyQt are simply not used enough together to be checked out thoroughly.  I found the risk of difficult to debug issues pretty high. This is especially true given the author of stackless has moved on to PyPy.  Let me apologize in advance - I wish I had the references I found for the author stopping development on stackless python and more detail on the errors I had to fix - I wasn't expecting to regurgitate the details on Stack Overflow.

So I chose to run PyQt on a vanilla Python instead of stackless.

BTW, I also thought that mixing signals/slots with stackless code would be confusing, as they are completely different methods of solving multi-threading problems.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**If you're interested in all that because of speed optimization:**

You may want to check out [**Unladen Swallow**](http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/) ( [Wikipedia here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unladen_Swallow) ). Google (because of YouTube being 100% Python) is working on a JIT compiler for Python that will increase its speed by 5-10x (bringing it much closer to Java speeds than the current virtual machine). The best part is that it **will work with all existing Python code** which means you don't have to fret with all the problems associated with other Python optimization projects.

I expect that if you're developing a large enough project to warrant the need for optimization at a low level, you'd be OK with developing in normal Python and then changing out of the current VM when Unladen Swallow comes out in production.

Comment: Thanks for response. I would like to use Stackless Python because its flow-of-control model fits nicely with my project.  For this project I place a higher priority on optimizing R&D speed than runtime speed (I predict that Stackless would also speed up the runtime)

Comment: Yea, I hear it does a bit (5-10% or more).